# Static function for sum & compareTo

Tags: java

Ok so basically this is my program it's about Students & Student Groups;
Each student has a name, ID and marks/points;
The program is working fine but what's missing is that the SUM function in the class StudentsGroup needs to be **static and to take a parameter of the "Group"   of which you need the sum of points**. My problem is that when I put the function and the ArrayList to static, the function returns both of the groups score combined and I don't know how to make it work

> //the program works correctly and returns the correct values about
>   everything; i only get those errors when i try to change the
>   sumOfPoints function to static

the two files that i have are:
Group 1:

61662126 Laurel 50
61662213 Mark 35.5
61662345 Yanny 67
61662127 Larry 27
61662125 Kevin 87.5

and Group 2:

61662126 Jason 70

61662213 Josh 25.5

61662345 Bobby 57

61662127 Megan 17

61662125 Drake 86.5

the correct output should be:
Total points of Group1: 267.0

Total points of Group2: 256.0

Comparing Group1 to Group2: 1

but when i put it to static it returns 523 in both which is both of the groups combined and i don't understand what im doing wrong

```
public interface IFile
{
    public void Load();
}





public class Student implements Comparable<Student> 
{

    private int facnum;
    private String name;
    private double points;

    public Student(int fn, String n, double p)
    {
        this.facnum = fn;
        this.name = n;
        this.points = p;
    }

    public void SetFN(int fn)
    {
        this.facnum = fn;
    }

    public void SetName(String n)
    {
        this.name = n;
    }

    public void SetPoints(double p)
    {
        this.points = p;
    }

    public int GetFN()
    {
        return this.facnum;
    }

    public String GetName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double GetPoints()
    {
        return this.points;
    }

        public boolean equals(Object s)
{
    if (this.GetFN() != ((Student)s).GetFN())
    {
        return false;
    }
        return true;
}

public int compareTo(Object s) 
{
    if(this.GetFN() < ((Student)s).GetFN())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    if(this.GetFN() > ((Student)s).GetFN())
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}


    public String toString()
    {
        return "Faculty Number: " + this.facnum + " Name: " + this.name + " Points: " + this.points + " \n";
    }
}




import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class StudentsGroup implements IFile, Comparable<Object>
{
    private String groupname;
    private List<Student>oStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();

    public StudentsGroup(String filename)
    {
        this.groupname = filename;
        Load();
    }

    public void Load(){
        try 
        {   
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(new File(this.groupname));
            while(sc.hasNextLine())
            {
                oStudent.add(new Student(sc.nextInt(),sc.next(),
                        sc.nextDouble()));
            }
        sc.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Input/Output Error...");
        }
    }


    public void printColl()
    {
        System.out.println(oStudent.toString());
    }

    public  List<Student> sortedListFN()
    {
        Collections.sort(oStudent);
        return oStudent;
    }

    public double sumOfPoints()
    {
        double sum = 0.00;

        for(Iterator<Student> it= oStudent.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            Student c = it.next();
            sum += c.GetPoints();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object s) 
    {
        if(this.sumOfPoints() < ((StudentsGroup) s).sumOfPoints())
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(this.sumOfPoints() > ((StudentsGroup) s).sumOfPoints())
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        StudentsGroup oGroup1 = new StudentsGroup("Group1.txt");
        oGroup1.printColl();
        System.out.println("Sorted order by FN: " + oGroup1.sortedListFN() + "\n");
        StudentsGroup oGroup2 = new StudentsGroup("Group2.txt");
        System.out.println("Total points of Group1: " + oGroup1.sumOfPoints() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Total points of Group2: " + oGroup2.sumOfPoints() + "\n");
        System.out.println("Comparing Group1 to Group2: " + oGroup1.compareTo(oGroup2));

    }


}
```

edit//the static method that i tried is changing oStudent to static:

```
private static List<Student>oStudent = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

obviously changing the sum function to static & editing the compareTo method:

```
public static double sumOfPoints(Object s)
    {
        double sum = 0.00;
        s  = new ArrayList<Student>(oStudent);

        for(Iterator<Student> it= ((List<Student>) s).iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            Student c = it.next();
            sum += c.GetPoints();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object s) 
    {
        if(this.sumOfPoints(this) < ((StudentsGroup) s).sumOfPoints(s))
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if(this.sumOfPoints(this) > ((StudentsGroup) s).sumOfPoints(s))
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

and the output:

```
System.out.println("Total points of Group1: " + oGroup1.sumOfPoints(oGroup1) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Total points of Group2: " + oGroup2.sumOfPoints(oGroup2) + "\n");
        System.out.println("Comparing Group1 to Group2: " + oGroup1.compareTo(oGroup2));
```

[and the output starts returning 523](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hNcm.png)

Comment: Show the code of the static method that you tried.

Comment: Your `equals` method needs to take `Object`, not `Student`. Add `@Override` annotations when you want to override, and the compiler will catch such things.

Comment: Edit your post, do not add comments.

Comment: okay i edited it @Robert

Comment: Unrelated: typically compareTo() also returns for 0 ... for "equal" values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your static method overwrites `s` with the inner object of that particular instance class:

```
s  = new ArrayList<Student>(oStudent);
```

I think your mistake is here. This is not how you use a static method of class. The correct way to do it is `StudentsGroup.sumOfPoints(yourObjectHere)`. A static method should not know about any field of a particular instance.